# Viewpager not showing in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager placed inside a ConstraintLayout, but it is not showing up at all. Any other view will show up no problems. Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/close_login_screen"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/icondelete"/>
                
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>
                
                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/login_view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"/>
                
                </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
                
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I use a LinearLayout for example, the ViewPager does show up, but it simply won't scroll to show the extra content. Not sure if this helps, but the final layout I want to achieve looks something like this:

[image]

But instead I have this:

[image]

Comment: Have you provided the `ViewPager` with the (phone no. & email) page fragments?

Comment: Yes, the fragments for both are there, and the contents show up fine in a linear layout,  but the drawback with that is the contents won't scroll.

Comment: I updated my answer and rebuild everything. Now the Viewpager is working as it should. Feel free to copy the classes and XML to try it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set everything up for you. You need to have a `BaseFragment` that will hold the `ViewPager`. The `Viewpager` invokes the 2 other Fragments. Here `FirstFragment` (Phone) and `SecondFragment` (Email). So first define your `BaseFragment.java` like this:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public BaseFragment(){
    }

    public static FirstFragment firstFragment;
    public static SecondFragment secondFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);


        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.login_view_pager);
        firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
        secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), 0);
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(firstFragment,"Phone");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(secondFragment,"Email");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
            super(fm, behavior);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragments.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitle.add(title);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitle.get(position);
        }


    }
}
```

And also define it's `fragment_base.xml` with the stuff you gave us:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".BaseFragment">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/close_login_screen"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/icondelete"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/login_view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="#121212"
                        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#121212"
                        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"/>

                </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Now the more unattractive part. Define `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` with it's Views. That will be hold from the `ViewPager` as `TabLayout`, your Phone and Email pages.

`FirstFragment.java`:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);


        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_phone);

        return view;
    }
}
```

`fragment_first.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView_phone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</ScrollView>
```

`SecondFragment.java`:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);


        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_email);

        return view;
    }
}
```

`fragment_second.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView_email"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</ScrollView>
```

---

**RESULT**

[image: Scrollable Viewpager]

Now you see the `Viewpager` is working properly.
If you want to make the fragment scrollable you need to add `ScrollView` in `fragment_first.xml` and `fragment_second.xml`. Cheers!

Comment: The viewPager does work OK with this approach, but it still does not scroll if the fragment layout has contents that overlaps the screen.

Comment: Okey, do you mean the BaseFragment or the Phone and Email Fragment that don't scroll?

Comment: As you can see in the picture your 2 Fragments can be scrolled by adding a ScrollView to it. I explained it at the very end of my updated answer.

Comment: aah I see! So I can only scroll the fragment itself, but not its parent container? I assumed the whole activity containing the fragments would be the one to scroll.

Comment: No that isn't possible and makes no sense in your case. You have a closing button that would be scrolled away. I think my suggested solution is the best to go with. (experienced). Feel free to tick this question as correct to help the community. Cheers!